# C#: Iterating through a huge datatable

Tags: c#, loops, datatable

Iterating through a datatable that contains about 40 000 records using for-loop takes almost 4 minutes. Inside the loop I'm just reading the value of a specific column of each row and concatinating it to a string.

I'm not opening any DB connections or something, as its a function which recieves a datatable, iterate through it and returns a string.

Is there any faster way of doing this?

Code goes here:

```
   private string getListOfFileNames(Datatable listWithFileNames)
   {     
        string whereClause = "";

            if (listWithFileNames.Columns.Contains("Filename"))
            {
                whereClause = "where filename in (";
                for (int j = 0; j < listWithFileNames.Rows.Count; j++)
                    whereClause += " '" + listWithFileNames.Rows[j]["Filename"].ToString() + "',";
            }
            whereClause = whereClause.Remove(whereClause.Length - 1, 1);
            whereClause += ")";    

        return whereClause;                
    }
```

Comment: please post some code

Comment: Did you try using some `LINQ` on the datatable?

Comment: It would be nice to see some code or provide more explanation of how you are going about it.  For example, if you aren't using the StringBuilder class to concatenate the strings that alone could be taking up a majority of the time.

Comment: If you are building up a huge string you may want to look at string builder or better yet writing the data to a file

Comment: Code added....Yes, I'm using simple **string**.

Answer (score 2):

1. Are you using a StringBuilder to concat the strings rather than just regular string concatenation?
2. Are you pulling back any more columns from the database then you really need to?  If so, try not to.  Only pull back the column(s) that you need.
3. Are you pulling back any more rows from the database then you really need to?  If so, try not to.  Only pull back the row(s) that you need.
4. How much memory does the computer have?  Is it maxing out when you run the program or getting close to it?  Is the processor at the max much or at all?  If you're using too much memory then you may need to do more streaming.  This means not pulling the whole result set into memory (i.e. a datatable) but reading each line one at a time.  It also might mean that rather than concatting the results into a string (or StringBuilder ) that you might need to be appending them to a file so as to not take up so much memory.

Answer (score 0):

Following linq statement have a where clause on first column and concat the third column in a variable.

```
 string CSVValues = String.Join(",", dtOutput.AsEnumerable()
                                                .Where(a => a[0].ToString() == value)
                                                .Select(b => b[2].ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - run it through a profiler, make sure you're looking at the right thing when optimizing.

Case in point, we had an issue we were sure was slow database interactions and when we ran the profiler the db barely showed up.

That said, possible things to try:

- if you have the memory available, convert the query to a list, this
  will force a full db read. Otherwise the linq will probably load in
  chunks doing multiple db queries.
- push the work to the db - if you can create a query than trims down
  the data you are looking at, or even calculates the string for you,
  that might be faster
- if this is something where the query is run often but the data rarely
  changes, consider copying the data to a local db (eg. sqlite) if
  you're using a remote db.
- if you're using the local sql-server, try sqlite, it's faster for
  many things.

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = dataTable
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(row => row.Field<string>("columnName"));

var colValueStr = string.join(",", value.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a dummy column in your table with an expression. Something like this:

```
DataColumn dynColumn = new DataColumn();

{
    dynColumn.ColumnName = "FullName";
    dynColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
    dynColumn.Expression = "LastName+' '-ABC";
}
UserDataSet.Tables(0).Columns.Add(dynColumn);
```

Later in your code you can use this dummy column instead. You don't need to rotate any loop to concatenate a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try using parallel for loop..
Here's the sample code..

```
Parallel.ForEach(dataTable.AsEnumerable(),
            item => { str += ((item as DataRow)["ColumnName"]).ToString(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

I've separated the job in small pieces and let each piece be handled by its own Thread. You can fine tune the number of thread by varying the nthreads number. Try it with different numbers so you can see the difference in performance.

```
private string getListOfFileNames(DataTable listWithFileNames)
{
    string whereClause = String.Empty;

    if (listWithFileNames.Columns.Contains("Filename"))
    {
        int nthreads = 8; // You can play with this parameter to fine tune and get your best time.
        int load = listWithFileNames.Rows.Count / nthreads; // This will tell how many items reach thread mush process.

        List<ManualResetEvent> mres = new List<ManualResetEvent>(); // This guys will help the method to know when the work is done.
        List<StringBuilder> sbuilders = new List<StringBuilder>(); // This will be used to concatenate each bis string.

        for (int i = 0; i < nthreads; i++)
        {
            sbuilders.Add(new StringBuilder()); // Create a new string builder
            mres.Add(new ManualResetEvent(false)); // Create a not singaled ManualResetEvent.

            if (i == 0) // We know were to put the very begining of your where clause
            {
                sbuilders[0].Append("where filename in (");
            }

            // Calculate the last item to be processed by the current thread
            int end = i == (nthreads - 1) ? listWithFileNames.Rows.Count : i * load + load;

            // Create a new thread to deal with a part of the big table.
            Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart((x) =>
            {
                // This is the inside of the thread, we must unbox the parameters
                object[] vars = x as object[];
                int lIndex = (int)vars[0];
                int uIndex = (int)vars[1];
                ManualResetEvent ev = vars[2] as ManualResetEvent;
                StringBuilder sb = vars[3] as StringBuilder;
                bool coma = false;

                // Concatenate the rows in the string builder
                for (int j = lIndex; j < uIndex; j++)
                {
                    if (coma)
                    {
                        sb.Append(", ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        coma = true;
                    }

                    sb.Append("'").Append(listWithFileNames.Rows[j]["Filename"]).Append("'");
                }

                // Tell the parent Thread that your job is done.
                ev.Set();
            }));

            // Start the thread with the calculated params
            t.Start(new object[] { i * load, end, mres[i], sbuilders[i] });
        }

        // Wait for all child threads to finish their job
        WaitHandle.WaitAll(mres.ToArray());

        // Concatenate the big string.
        for (int i = 1; i < nthreads; i++)
        {
            sbuilders[0].Append(", ").Append(sbuilders[i]);
        }

        sbuilders[0].Append(")"); // Close your where clause

        // Return the finished where clause
        return sbuilders[0].ToString();
    }

    // Returns empty
    return whereClause;
}
```

Comment: @sunsa428 Yeah sure, I've modified my code to perform the job that your code is doing. So you just copy/paste/try.  I'm just using multi-threading to get the job done in faster time, and using string builders to concatenate strings, that's pretty much faster than concatenating strings with strings.